# What could be wrong with this php code?

Tags: php

i'm doing  a voting system. After displaying all candidates from my DB, a user is to click on a candidate's image to vote. 
I am trying to use GET to get the matric number of a candidate so as to echo a text.
The Error is this: Upon loading the page, an error message comes up even without clicking on any image as follows-

Notice: Undefined index: user in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\onlinevoting\vote.php on line 74

Voted

What could be wrong?

```
if (isset($_POST['display'])) {
    $position_selected = $_POST['position_selected'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM candidate WHERE position='$position_selected'";
    $run_query = mysqli_query($db_conn, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($run_query) > 0) {

        $nr = mysqli_num_rows($run_query);
        echo '<h3 style="font-size:2em;text-align:center">('.$nr.') ASPIRANTS FOR <span style="color:maroon;text-decoration:underline"> '.$position_selected.'</span></h3>';

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query)) {
            echo '<div class="asp">
            <a class="votelink" href="?user='.$row["matno"].'"><img title="Click Image to Vote" height="300" width="300" src="data:image;base64,'.$row[6].' "></a><br><p style="font-weight:bolder;font-size:1.5em;width:300px;text-align:center;margin-bottom:0px;">'.$row[1].'<br><b><p style="font-size:1em;font-weight:bold;width:300px;text-align:center;margin-bottom:0px;">'.$row[2].'/'.$row[3].'</p><b><br>
            </div>';

        }     
        if ($_GET['user'] == $row["matno"]) {
            echo 'Voted';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<p style="color:darkred;font-weight:bolder;font-size:1.6em;text-align:center;">No candidate for this Position</p>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: *"What could be wrong with this php code?"* - Stack protip: That's a bad choice for a title.

Comment: You... have an *"Undefined index"*.

Comment: Would be nice to define which line is line 74 with the error. I'm betting its <a class . . .

Comment: User variable is undefined

Comment: You have an undefined index: user in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\onlinevoting\vote.php on line 74

Comment: You check for a $_POST variable at the beginning of this script. Then you go and reference a $_GET variable. You cannot have BOTH on a single submission of a page to a script!! **Refactor** the code with the _brain engaged_

Comment: how do i go about the refactoring?

Comment: **refactor = rewrite**

Comment: You are "trying to use GET to get the matric number of a candidate", however, at the top of your code, you are testing for `if (isset($_POST['display'])) {` using the POST super global, and nested within it you have `if ($_GET['user'] == $row["matno"]) {`.  While it is actually possible to have such a situation, I believe that's where your problem stems from. What method is your form using: GET or POST? If GET, why the `isset($_POST)` test. If POST, does the form's action attribute have the `user` variable in its query string? You could begin to troubleshoot the problem from here.

Comment: How about a [MAX Factor](http://maxfactor-international.com/) instead Smokey? @RiggsFolly

Comment: @NaijaProgrammer Is that not what I said 3 minutes before

Comment: *"there is none in the form –  Joel Amawhe 33 secs ago"*, form, what form? form method is; none?

Comment: You would have to really PLASTER IT ON to cover all the cracks in that code Ralph @Fred-ii-

Comment: The things you can do with thick and slick lipstick Smokey @RiggsFolly

Comment: no user variable on the form. the method is post

Answer (score 1):

From what you've posted I am going to guess that you're not checking that the `$_GET` variable `user` has been set.

Change this line

```
if ($_GET['user'] == $row["matno"]) {
```

to

```
if ((isset($_GET['user'])) && ($_GET['user'] == $row["matno"])) {
```

Comment: Except that execution will never get to that IF if the form was submitted via GET as its inside another if which tests for the existance of a $_POST variable!!!

Comment: This is true; I hadn't spotted the `$_POST` aspects at the beginning of the code.  Thinking about it, I've never attempted to pass POST and GET variables at the same time, but I am not entirely sure whether that's actually impossible.

Comment: Well I suppose they could change $_GET and $_POST to $_REQUEST. But not without testing EVERY variable for its existance before going anywhere near it. **This is not a serious suggestion at a solution**

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as an answer rather than a comment.

You are "trying to use GET to get the matric number of a candidate", however, at the top of your code, you are testing for if

`(isset($_POST['display'])) {`

using the POST super global, and nested within it you have

`if ($_GET['user'] == $row["matno"]) {`.

While it is actually possible to have such a situation, I believe that's where your problem stems from. What method is your form using: GET or POST? If GET, why the `isset($_POST)` test. If POST, does the form's action attribute have the user variable in its query string? You could begin to troubleshoot the problem from here.

Basically, PHP is reporting that the 'user' array member isn't set, which most likely means your form's action page does not include the `user` variable in its query string.

I propose two possible solutions to this.

First, and most preferably, use a hidden input field in your form, and set its value to the user's id. Then, instead of testing for `$_GET['user']`, test for `$_POST['user']`. The HTML snippet for the hidden input field would be like :

```
<input type="hidden" name="user" value="Whatever_user_id_is"/>
```

Then replace

`if ($_GET['user'] == $row["matno"]) {`

with

`if ($_POST['user'] == $row["matno"]) {`.

An alternative approach, if you wish to stick with the `if ($_GET['user'] == $row["matno"]) {` syntax/pattern, is to include the `user` variable as part of the form's action attribute:

```
<form method="post" action="YOUR_FORMS_ACTION_PAGE?user=what_ever_user_is">
```

That way, when you submit the form, the `user` variable will be present in the GET super global array.

Answer (score 0):

That should be better

```
if (isset($_POST['user'])) {
    if ($_POST['user'] == $row["matno"])) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Except that execution will never get to that IF if the form was submitted via GET as its inside another if which tests for the existance of a $_POST variable!!!

Comment: I really don't understand

Comment: watch if you have a user variable in your form and do you use $_GET[] or $_POST method in your form

Comment: there is none and the form is using a post

Comment: What none? your variable or the method? You must use get or post method in your form and you should have an user input or whatever

Comment: there is no variable but there is a method, which is POST

Comment: then you should use     isset($_POST['user'])  instead of     $_GET['user'] and don't expect to get an user variable if you don't have one in your form...

Comment: the user variable is attached to this link <a class="votelink" href="?user='.$row["matno"].'"><img title="Click Image to Vote" height="300" width="300" src="data:image;base64,'.$row[6].' "></a> to build a url query string

Comment: then put it in your form like a hidden input to get your variable or use $_SESSION